# Control FPS of Kinect v2

Tags: c#, image, kinect-v2

I want to control FPS rate of Microsoft Kinect v2 , For example if image processing computation taking more time then FPs rate will slow and if image processing computation taking less time then Fps rate will fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
The best you can do is to acquire at the maximum fps (30 or 15 according to the light for color camera) and then discard frames if the processing is not finished.
Alex